# Drupal6: how to link a view to another

Tags: view, drupal-6

I have 2 views that show the content of 2 CCK content types.
When the user clicks an item of the first view I would like to filter the content of the second view by filtering for the selected item in the first view, all on the same page (using ajax, I believe).
How can I do a similar thing? Should I also use panels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you: http://drupal.org/node/1099194#comment-4290352